# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django rest framework view that contains the following code -

```
trgmst_info = request.DATA['trgmst_info'][0]
request_accts = ['request-dev', 'request-qa', 'request-uat', 'request-prod']
request.DATA['trgmst_info'] = [rd.replace(request_accts, settings.REQUEST_ACCT) for rd in request.DATA['trgmst_info']]
```

The value for request.DATA['trgmst_info'][0] is as follows -

```
"<eventmon><conn>24</conn><action>3</action><folder/><mailbox>Inbox</mailbox><condition><condcount>1</condcount><criteria1>Sender</criteria1><ctext1>test_MESSage</ctext1><csensitive1>Y</csensitive1></condition><msgbody>Y</msgbody><evtmtrg>Inbox (request-dev@mailserver.blah.com)</evtmtrg></eventmon>"
```

What I'm trying to do is scan for one of the request_accts and replace it with what the value is in settings.REQUEST_ACCT

All that keeps happening is the following error though -

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Traceback:
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  400.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  397.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Tidal\API\views.py" in put
  464.                 request.DATA['trgmst_info'] = [rd.replace(request_accts, settings.REQUEST_ACCT) for rd in request.DATA['trgmst_info']]

Exception Type: TypeError at /deploy/event/
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

edit - if I sneak the following code in after the first line -

```
print trgmst_info
```

It returns `<`.  If I change the first line to the following -

```
trgmst_info = request.DATA['trgmst_info']
```

The print returns everything -

```
<eventmon><conn>24</conn><action>3</action><folder/><mailbox>Inbox</mailbox><condition><condcount>1</condcount><criteria1>Sender</criteria1><ctext1>test_MESSage</ctext1><csensitive1>Y</csensitive1></condition><msgbody>Y</msgbody><evtmtrg>Inbox (request-dev@mailserver.blah.com)</evtmtrg></eventmon>
```

But the same error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string.replace() uses strings as parameters not lists. 
request_accts
Is a list.

I'm not a django expert but maybe this will work:

```
trgmst_info = request.DATA['trgmst_info'][0]
request_accts = ['request-dev', 'request-qa', 'request-uat', 'request-prod']
for rep in request_accts:
    request.DATA['trgmst_info'] = [rd.replace(rep, settings.REQUEST_ACCT) for rd in request.DATA['trgmst_info']]
```

Comment: ah I was looking in the wrong post.  So how do I get it to check the string for each value provided in my list?